# how to store array inside object formate data in solr 5

Tags: python, solr, lucene, jetty, solr5

i am trying to save data in solr 5 in one fields as json formate

```
example 
"eligibility": "[{\"state_id\": 0, \"name\": \"Anywhere in India\", \"id\": 5000}]",
```

simple data is working

```
"location_search_id": ["5000"],
```

that eligibility data is not supporting in solr  5

```
<field name="eligibility" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
```